# Understanding Addressables: When do they need to be included as AssetReference?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having trouble understanding exactly how to use AdressableAssets.

In my (non-addressable scene) "Init", I am trying to reference a ScriptableObject and a scene (named "mainMenu").
I do this via:

```cs
public class Initializer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private AssetReference mySUPERAssetAF;
    [SerializeField] private AssetReference mainMenuSceneAF;

//...

    void Start()
    {
            // load the next scene
            mainMenuSceneAF.LoadSceneAsync(LoadSceneMode.Additive).Completed += (obj) => { 
                // load the asset
                mySUPERAssetAF.LoadAssetAsync().Completed += (obj) => {
                    obj.Result.doSomething();
                };
            };
    }
}
```

In the addressable-scene ("mainMenu") loaded above, I also have a script that should use the same SuperAsset.
I noticed that I do NOT have to include it there via AssetReference, but "directly":

```cs
public class MainMenuController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private SuperType mySUPERAsset;

//...

    void Start()
    {
        mySUPERAsset.doSomething();
    }
}
```

By the way: Why the two scenes should use the same SuperAsset is because in practice they are ScriptableObjects, whereby both should work on the same instance. In this way, I create an event system, so to speak. But that's just by the way...

Can someone explain to me why this works and why I don't have to access the asset via AssetReference in the MainMenu-Scene?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I would just assume that in the second case the scene loading takes longer as it already loads the asset as part of the scene loading itself - while in the first snippet the scene loads faster (-> doesn't appear as freeze) but then the asst is loaded asynchronous